# Creating a bounded logarithmic graph in Excel

Tags: excel, graph

In Excel
I know how to produce a logarithmic graph with X axis between 0 to 1.

However how do I create a graph with a logarithmic X axis that is only between a certain range e.g., 99-100

Comment: Can't you change the minimum and maximum of the axis to `99` and `100` after selecting `logarithmic`? Also, this question is better suited for superuser.com since it has nothing to do with programming.

Comment: I can set the bounds but then the log scale  disappear!!

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of ways to do this. The simplest might be to start with two columns. In A1, B1, put the headers (like "x" and "log(x)").

Then in A2, start with 99. Then in A3, place 99.1 and increase by 0.1 in each row.

In B2, press the formula button (the fx) toward the top. Search for the function log. Click OK. For function arguments, put A2 in for the number and 10 for the base. (This tells Excel to calculate the base-10 log of whatever number you have in A2. You did not specify if you wanted a base-10 log or a natural logarithm.)

Next, copy down from B2 to the last number in A.

Finally, select the headers down to the last line. Use Excel's graph function (from the Insert tab => Scatter and whichever looks good to you).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the quick answers, but I am not sure they provide me the solution. Let me better explain my need. I have a function for which i want to draw a graph. The x values are: 99, 99.9, 99.95, 99.99, 99.9925, 99.995, 99.9975, 99.999 - so between 99 and 99.9 there are 2 values and then under 99.99 inclusive another 2 values and then the 4 rest are below 100. for each of these x values there is an f(x) = y value (between 1 to 9). Showing that on regular x axis group most of the points together so it is not possible to distinguish between them. Thus I want a horizontal logarithmic scale. If the x values would be between 0-100 this is trivial. But between 99-100 - looks like excel has a bug. Or maybe you have a real solution for that?